# "A network cable is not properly plugged in or may be broken" in wireless laptop

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, laptop

After installing "intel driver and support assistant" and restarting my laptop, I can't connect to my Hotspot anymore. I tried fixing it by uninstalling my Intel wireless in device manager but didn't worked out.

Windows 10 troubleshooting says "A network  cable is not properly plugged in or may be broken". The problem is I am on a laptop using wireless. It doesn't have any cable to be fixed.

I'm confused about it, so I'm here to get help.

Comment: 1-Have you tried to download the wireless driver from the manufacturer website (ex: Dell, HP, Lenovo, etc.)? 2-Can you list your laptop model & WiFi card model? 3-Have you removed DSA (Intel Driver Support Assistant) SW?

Comment: @gregg1) I'm going to download it after your suggestion. 2) I have Lenovo Y700 with Intel AC 8260 wireless. 3) yes I did but didn't worked out.

Comment: @gregg It is fixed by installing the last driver. Thank you.

Comment: I posted it as an answer if you'd like to accept it? Or upvote comments since I work for those points :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Please update the wireless driver from Lenovo's site](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/legion-series/legion-y7000-2019/downloads/DS539656). It appears there is no Y700 model at first glance, but a couple variations of the Y700***0***

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/992849)

Comment: I've modified my answer. OP's question had comments detailing why it wasn't a robust answer at first